# why persisting class properties/fields is useful

Tags: jpa, data-structures, persistence, jdo

I have started learning JPA and I got understanding of what persistence of a property is from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1432760/explaining-persistent-data-structures-in-simple-terms).

But I do not quite understand

1. why I need to persist properties?
2. whether I need to persist all properties or just some particular ones?

Please give explanation with examples, thanks

Update:

Example:
What is the difference between

```
@PersistenceCapable(identityType = IdentityType.APPLICATION)
public class Movie {

    @PrimaryKey
    @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
    private Key key;

    @Persistent
    private String title;

    @Persistent
    @Extension(vendorName="datanucleus", key="gae.unindexed", value="true")
    private String imageType;

    @Persistent
    private Blob image;
//getter, setters
}
```

and

```
@PersistenceCapable(identityType = IdentityType.APPLICATION)
public class Movie {
    @PrimaryKey
    @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
    private Key key;

    private String title;


    @Extension(vendorName="datanucleus", key="gae.unindexed", value="true")
    private String imageType;


    private Blob image;
//getter, setters
}
```

Comment: Let's say you're implementing Amazon.com. Don't you think it might be necessary to have a database containing all the books, records, customers, prices, stocks, etc.? And wouldn't it be nice if you could just say, hey, find the book with the given ID, and get a Book object as a result, rather than a row containing columns? That's what JPA is all about. You persist what you need to be persistent. You design your entities and their properties based on the tables and columns you want in the database. You don't just take a random object and make it persistent just for the fun of it.

Comment: Ye I know that JPA allows you to access objects faster, `@Entity` does this job. What I am asking is why to use annotations such as `@Basic`, etc. which are just for properties/fields of class

Comment: `@Basic` is almost never used. It's only used to make a property lazy-fetched, which you almost never want. Do you have some more concrete question? Maybe you're just looking for a JPA tutorial, or for the javadoc of the annotations? http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/

Comment: updated question with an example from JDO

Comment: I don't know much about JDO. To know what the rules are, read the specifications: http://db.apache.org/jdo/specifications.html. In JPA, a field of an entity is persistent by default, without any annotation needed. You use annotations to tell JPA which column to use to store the fields, etc. Choose JPA or JDO (but I wouldn't choose JDO: it's dead), and read some tutorial, or even the specifications.

Comment: There is no difference between those two JDO examples (well, if the underlying JDO implementation supports "Blob" ... which is a GAE specific type). A String (and many other Java types) are by default persistent. All decent JDO docs (Apache JDO, DataNucleus) state that clearly ... GAE docs OTOH give false impressions. But that doesn't answer why you ask the question for JPA. And no, JDO is continually developed and used, stick to the question

Comment: Thx, that answers my question, because I thought to persist field you need to put some annotation.

Comment: Of course, JDO is still actively developed and used, but not by many people. Number of questions tagged JDO here: 905. Number of questions tagged JPA here: 14066. And JDO is older than JPA.